# Нужно узнать сказанное после команды

Tags: python, webbrowser

Я делаю голосового ассистента, и мне нужно знать что было сказано **после** команды открой в ютубе то есть я говорю: открой в ютубе смешарики и он с помощью webbrowser ищет в ютубе смешарики

```
elif "открой в ютубе" in message:
            say_message("Открываю!")
```

Comment: ну как банальный вариант отделять `message` от `"открой в ютубе"` и собирать из оставшейся части строку с словом `f"Открываю {<отделенная часть>}!"`